# Place divs one below the other

Tags: html, css

I want to place my `banner` divs one below the other. I tried using different combinations of `display` and `position` properties but it doesnt work. They are displaying on top of each other.I want my output as firstly the banner,then below it the row of images and below the row the second banner.

```css
.row div:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}
.row div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5%;
}
.row div img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
.row div a {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #515150;
}
.row div a:hover,
.row div img:hover {
  color: black;
}
.img-container {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 150px;
}
.banner {
  padding-top: 20px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  margin-left: 5%;
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <h3>TOP SELLING</h3>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="img-container">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="martial.png">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="img-container">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="bvb.png">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="img-container">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="ars.png">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="img-container">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="lewandowski1.png">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="banner">
  <h3>TOP SELLING</h3>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="img-container">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="martial.png">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="img-container">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="bvb.png">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="img-container">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="ars.png">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="img-container">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="lewandowski1.png">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

PS: I also tried using different ids for the banners but it doesnt work.

Comment: your banners are one below other. I don't understand what's the problem. Please explain

Comment: Please distinguish between "below the other" and "on top of each other".

Comment: Also, div elements are block-level by default, so they should do what you describe without additional styling.

Comment: By on top of each other i mean this http://postimg.org/image/zfan1ua0h/

Comment: Given *that* markup and *that* CSS, I don't see how you could get the result you are describing. I suspect the problem lies with some code you haven't shown us. Try constructing a [real, reduced test case](http://sscce.org/) (and making use of the [snippets feature](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) so we can see how it renders.

Comment: @Quentin Please refer the snippet and the imagelink posted above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either add `.banner {clear:both}` or remove the unnecessary `float` from `.img-container` (the `display:inline-block` already does that job.)